# My laptop suddenly lost all its audio devices

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio

Today after turning on my laptop (MSI GS70 Stealth Pro) a Windows error message appeared, with Windows then proceeding to "fix" it. I didn't bother checking what was the error because it looked like it was fixed and after rebooting again everything seemed fine.

Problem is, I lost all the audio devices installed on the computer, i.e. the speakers and the headset jacks. The sound icon is stuck on "mute" and by clicking on it the automatic error solving procedure is carried out, with no results.

After multiple reboots, I tried to download the latest audio drivers from the MSI website, but that didn't work as well.

I can't recall doing anything weird these past days which could have caused problems.

I'm running windows 8.1.

I don't really know what else could that be, or how to fix it.

EDIT: no audio devices are shown in the device manager. I've tried to use the recovery tool but it got stuck because of Avast, for some reason (apparently, a certain file cannot be deleted).

I've also tried with a live Linux distro and no sound was played even there.

I'm starting to think it's an hardware problem, even though it seems quite weird.

EDIT 2: For some mysterious reason I'm still trying to fathom, the problem fixed itself after turning off and then turning the pc on again. Now I'm wondering whether this kind of operation is different from a reboot. Should I answer my own question? It seems quite silly, however.

Comment: Do you still see the devices if you go the the device manager. E.g. [start] [run] `devmgmt.msc` or its windows 8 equivalent?

Comment: If I remember correctly I don't, there may be the Nvidia driver for some reason. At the moment I can't check, unfortunately.

Comment: @Hennes no devices appear in the driver manager.